# How to calculate buy back token amount on quipuswap v2?

Tags: dex

I have a **token-tez pool** on **quipuswap v2** dex.

I want to calculate how much tez should I provide to dex to buy back the `x` amount of tokens from the dex.

What is the formula to calculate this?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The approach is similar to V1.

You need to get reserves and supply using view in the same way as you did before and then use the approach below to calculate the result.

Here is a reference implementation in TS for calculating how many token A you have to provide to buy `bTokenAmount` of token b:

```
export const findAmmSwapInput = (
  bTokenAmount: BigNumber,
  pair: RoutePairWithDirection
) => {
  const feeRatio = getPairFeeRatio(pair);
  const numerator = pair.aTokenPool.times(bTokenAmount);
  const denominator = pair.bTokenPool.minus(bTokenAmount).times(feeRatio);
  const input = numerator.idiv(denominator).plus(1);
  return input.isGreaterThan(0) ? input : new BigNumber(Infinity);
};
```

Notes:
`idiv` - division where only integer part is left (ex. 3.idiv(2) = 1)
`feeRatio`  - 0.9965